# Logging to a single file across different modules in python

Tags: python, logging

I have a python project where I want to log multiple events across different modules in a single rotating file. I am using [logzero](https://github.com/metachris/logzero) for this.

For example:
If I need logging from **init**.py and **main**.py, how can I using only a single log file to log both the events?

Comment: I don't know how you structured your code, but did you think about passing the logger object as argument to the several classes (maybe to `__int__(self, logger)`) or define it as constant in `my_logger.py` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the same log file from different python files:

```
logzero.logfile("logfile.log", maxBytes=1000000, backupCount=3)
```

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://logzero.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Features section):

**Multiple loggers can write to the same logfile (also across multiple Python files).**