# How to print to a single file from different modules in verilog?

Tags: verilog

As you know `$fdisplay` can print info into a file. But if you instantiate a module (like a **BFM**:Bus functional model) several times in the test bench and each of them has `$fdisplay`, then a problem may occur : Simultaneous access to a file

I my expriene that issue causes a not neat and tidy output file.

So how can I achieve my goal?

Python-Equivalent of my question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886582).

P.S. The simulator's console has limitation of what can be aggregated and my logs are somewhat long. So I should print them to file. Also merging all verilog codes into one is not possible at all.(Think how the BFM models are)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the output from your BFMs to go into a single file, your problem is not with `$fdisplay` but with `$fopen`. You need to create a top level function that calls `$fopen` only if it has not been called before.

```
integer file=0;
function integer bfm_fopen;
  begin
   if (file)
       bfm_fopen = file;
   else begin
       file = $fopen("logfile");
       bfm_fopen = file;
     end
   end
endfunction
```

Then call top_level.bfm_fopen from your BFMs

Comment: In your `else` you should add this after `$fopen` line : `bfm_fopen = file;`